# Where does the inverse seconds unit come from in the association constant?

Tags: biochemistry, lab-techniques

I'm working to determine K<sub>d</sub>(s) kinetically by generating association and disassociation curves.  K<sub>on</sub> (association constant, or on-rate) is in inverse seconds multiplied by inverse molar.  I get that the molar comes from concentration, but where do the seconds come from?

Answer (score 1):

First order association reaction:

$$\ce{A + B <=>[k_f][k_r] AB}$$

Rate of association (units: concentration per time) = $k_f\times[A]\times[B]$

 Since [A] and [B] are concentrations and LHS is conc. per time the units of $k_f$ has to be such that it gives conc per time when multiplied by conc<sup>2</sup> ([A] ×[B]) 
 Which is conc<sup>-1</sup> × time<sup>-1</sup>

Rate of dissociation (conc. per time) = $k_r\times[AB]$

 Therefore units of $k_r$ would be time<sup>-1</sup>.

Dissociation constant is actually $\dfrac{k_r}{k_f}$; Its units therefore would be conc.